# Is it possible to use extended regular expressions with mod_sed?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to use extended regular expression syntax in a mod_sed rule - specifically the or operator |, does anyone know of a way to do this or an alternative approach?
I've looked at the authors blog - https://blogs.oracle.com/basant/entry/using_mod_sed_to_filter and the apache doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_sed.html but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\|` operator is a GNU extension, and mod_sed implements sed as implemented in Solaris 10, so this is likely not possible.

Comment: That's what I thought but I came here for hope!

Comment: I hope they add it in a future version!  (How's that for hope?)  :-)

Comment: It'll do. It seems a strange decision to base it off vanilla rather than extended sed, but I guess there's performance considerations.